# An embedded iframe player blocks official advertising

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have a problem with the Iframe API. 
I made a player that plays youtube video, and the core of the playback is based on the iframe API. But my app has been recently removed from Google play, and I've been informed by email that my app blocked the youtube ADs. According to the Iframe API's documentation, there are two ways to embed a player.Using the  Or use the iframe player API. But I wrote the code in strict accordance with the document, no matter which way I used it, there was no advertisement. So is it that I accidentally blocked the youtube AD or the embedded player itself without advertising? However, in principle, I should write my application strictly according to the official documents, which should not be the problem. Here is the document address:https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en.
Looking forward to your answers, thank you.